# Ordering rows in table based on multiple columns grouped together

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by

I have data in a table in a specific structure. Here is the screenshot of it:

[image]

I want all these rows to be sorted based on the order of State_ID in their individual batch. Here is my desired output:

[image]

We can say that I want rows to be sorted based on the smallest to largest State_ID in their individual batch. It means that all the Branches having max State_ID as 95 would be arranged next to each other, then branch with State_ID as 100, then finally branch with State_ID as 104.

I have created a sample sql script for it too.

```
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE(
  State_ID INT,
  Branch INT,
  ID INT
);

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 94,1,1
UNION ALL SELECT 95,1,2
UNION ALL SELECT 94,2,3
UNION ALL SELECT 95,2,4
UNION ALL SELECT 94,3,5
UNION ALL SELECT 103,3,6
UNION ALL SELECT 104,3,7
UNION ALL SELECT 94,4,8
UNION ALL SELECT 95,4,9
UNION ALL SELECT 94,5,10
UNION ALL SELECT 96,5,11
UNION ALL SELECT 100,5,12
UNION ALL SELECT 94,6,13
UNION ALL SELECT 95,6,14
```

When I tried ordering based on State_ID and then Branch, it arranged all the rows with State_ID as 94 together, which I dont want. So, how can I achieve my desired result in the simplest and fastest approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using a CTE like so

```
;WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT T.Branch, MIN(T.State_ID) 'Min_StateId', MAX(T.State_ID) 'Max_StateId'
    FROM @tbl T
    GROUP BY T.Branch
)
SELECT B.*
FROM @tbl B
INNER JOIN cteX X ON X.Branch = B.Branch
ORDER BY X.Max_StateId, Branch, State_ID
```